# Hide folder_contents from unauthenticated users in Plone

Tags: security, permissions, plone

I have just noticed that, by default, `http://host/yourplonesite/folder/folder_contents` will always reveal the contents of a Plone folder.

Is it possible to hide `folder/folder_contents` from unauthenticated users? (Think `Options -Indexes` in httpd)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This controlled by the "List folder contents" permission. You should adjust the related workflow - in particular the permission-role mapping maintained by workflows.

Comment: Thanks! For completeness, the setting is at `http://host/yourplonesite/manage_access`.

Answer (score 4):

Also worth noting is that the folder contents list will never list any content the user doesn't otherwise have permission to see.